# Add value into tuple (zip() inside for loop ) in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to format a list of list into a list of tuples, the desired outcome is:

```
>>A = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>A.append([1, 2, 3])
>>A.append([1, 2, 3])
>>print A
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

And my desired output is:

```
>>zip (A[0],A[1],A[2])
[(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Now imagine that the list A is very large and I cannot do that process writing a small line of code, if I try to loop the zip() function the outcome is as follows:

```
>>print zip (A[0],a)
>>[(1, (1, 1, 1)), (2, (2, 2, 2)), (3, (3, 3, 3))]
```

The nasty solution that I came up was using a recursive loop:

```
>>B = zip(A[0])
>>for idx,val in enumerate(A):
    for idx1,val1 in enumerate(B):
        B[idx1] = val1 + (A[idx][idx1],)
```

That returns the desired result:

```
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3, 3)]
```

Hence, is there a proper/cleaner/faster way to solve this problem?

(Because it is an embedded package of Python I cannot use Pandas nut NumPy is allowed in an early version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `zip(*A)`, which is exactly `zip(A[0],A[1],...)`

(that's true for any function, not just zip). https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!!